# Kafka Connect JdbcSourceConnector ExtractField leaves double quotes around string

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am using Kafka Connect JdbcSourceConnector to stream DB table rows into a topic. In the Connect configuration, I have these lines in order to populate the Kafka message bodies from the `value` column of the table:

```
  "transforms": "extract",
  "transforms.extract.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField$Value",
  "transforms.extract.field": "value",
```

It basically works, but the message body comes with extra double quote characters around the string, which I totally unexpected. For instance, if a table row has `"value1"`(excluding the quotes) in the column then the Kafka message body for the row comes as `"\"value1\""`(excluding the outer quotes).

Is this an expected behavior of ExtractField? Is there a work-around for this? My KafkaConnect version is 2.2.2 and the broker version is 2.5.0 if that matters.

Comment: What serialization format are you using for the producer and the Connect converter? Field extraction preserves types, so strings with quotes will stay quoted

Comment: Sounds to me like you're consuming JSON data as a string (or re-serializing a string to JSON), which yes, quotes would be escaped

Comment: @OneCricketeer I don't specify any serialization format. Everything is by default when it comes to serialization. Is there a quick way to get rid of the quotes? Do I have to customize the serialization somehow?

Comment: There's no default format. In the connector, you would have `value.converter` defined in one of the property files. Other than that, it's unclear how you are actually consuming the data from the topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue by specifying `value.converter` like this:

```
  "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
```

With this config, I don't see the extra double quote characters any more.